I am looking for a phrase which could be used to describe a situation in which there is just no numerical way in which victory is possible
Think of an election in which a candidate is losing by 100,000 votes, and there are only 115,000 outstanding ballots. I am looking for a phrase to describe this, for some reason I am defaulting to numbers game, but that does not seem entirely accurate.

A forgone conclusion?

Could you give a sample sentence where you would use this phrase?

Perhaps the phrase "Game over"? You want to say the adversary is too far behind to win.  If I can come up with a better expression, I'll post it as an answer.

Huh? "a candidate is losing by 100,000 votes, and there are only 115,000 outstanding ballots" - this is very unlikely but not impossible. Do you mean there are fewer ballots than votes needed, or do you want a word for a situation which is unlikely but numerically possible? (I think there are various terms in sports leagues for situations where teams have certain probabilities of winning/losing, probably varying by country, but do you want one for politics? Or will this be moot in a few hours anyway?)

When people say "no numerical way" they normally mean it is a "mathematical certainty", which the example you describe is not.

This question is similar to: Word for absolutely bound to occur. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. 'A racing certainty' and 'a foregone conclusion' can doubtless be found by looking for synonyms for  'inevitable/inevitability' (the duplicate was closed for lack of research by a keen moderator)..

Something like

Although it is [conceivable / numerically possible] that candidate X could still win, as there
are 115,000 outstanding ballots, it is highly unlikely as they are
trailing by 100,000 votes.

Or did you mean something else?

Clinch means to secure something without a doubt. When someone clinches a contest, they are mathematically sure (not just very likely) to win, even if the contest hasn't ended yet. This could occur in an election where one person leads by more than the number of outstanding untabulated votes, or in a sports season where one team statistically secures their spot in the post-season playoffs before the season is over.
I'll note the example given in the question seems a little backwards, and is not an example of a clinched election - the losing candidate is merely unlikely to win, but theoretically could make up a 100k vote deficit with 115k votes left to count. It is not an example of a scenario in which there is "no numerical way in which victory is possible" - the trailing candidate can in fact win by earning 107,501 votes, even if doing so is virtually impossible in practice.
